# Detect if parent element binds to child's @Output in Angular

Tags: angular

I was wondering if, for example, you have an angular component like this

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    ...
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() previous = new EventEmitter<void>();

    ngOnInit() {
       // Detect if parent is listening for `previous` events
    }
}
```

I can detect the differences (inside the child component) between the following two use cases:

```
<app-child (previous)="onPrevious"></app-child>
```

and

```
<app-child></app-child>
```

What I would like to achieve with this is that I like to determine if I should show a `previous` button or not. If no one is listening for it, I can hide it. If this is not possible, I can of course add an `@Input() showPreviousButton`.

Comment: I think it will be much better if you move your buttons in the Parent component, or append them in a child by `ng-content`? What do you think?

Comment: I guess your solution is valid in many cases, but I'm building a wizard. Each wizard step has these buttons, so I moved them into one component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `EventEmitter` extends the RxJS's `Subject`, then, I think you can use the [Subject.observed](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subject#observed) read-only property to check if the parent is subscribed to it or not.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  // Detect if parent is listening for `previous` events
  if (this.previous.observed) {
    // The parent is listening for `previous` events
  }
}
```